# Press any key - Which key to press?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I see `press any key...` on my screen and:

1. I'm wondering which key I should press...

   OR
2. I'm pressing a key, but nothing happens!

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2a/Keyboard-anykey.jpg

Comment: Uhh err Fabby? :-P

Comment: Voting to close as too broad since this depends a lot on the application asking.

Comment: @muru: [SOHF](http://gaarde.org/acronyms/?lookup=SOHF)?  :P  >:)

Comment: [Get a room! :P](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new)

Comment: @muri Let me in =)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR** In most cases the <kbd>Any</kbd> key is the space bar.

---

Check your skills

```
sudo apt-get install xautomation
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys
printf "%s\n\t%s\n" "\"notify-send 'Any key'\"" "space" > ./foo
xbindkeys -f ./foo
```

check your skills and after that `killall xbindkeys`, maybe with copy'n'paste **;)**

---

BTW, I have the <kbd>Any</kbd> key. Works great.

[image]

<sub>[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Any_key)</sub>

Comment: :D  You just stole that from the comments!

Comment: @Fabby Sure, it's open source =)

Comment: @Fabby Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me an upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers ;)

Comment: I upvoted it before I wrote the comment!

Answer (score 10):

On this example keyboard:

<kbd>Esc</kbd>      <kbd>F1</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd>    <kbd>F5</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd>    <kbd>F9</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>    <kbd>[Prnt](http://askubuntu.com)</kbd>  <kbd>[Scrl](http://askubuntu.com)</kbd>  <kbd>[Pse](http://askubuntu.com)</kbd> 

  <kbd>`</kbd>   <kbd>1</kbd>   <kbd>2</kbd>   <kbd>3</kbd>   <kbd>4</kbd>   <kbd>5</kbd>   <kbd>6</kbd>   <kbd>7</kbd>   <kbd>8</kbd>   <kbd>9</kbd>   <kbd>0</kbd>   <kbd>-</kbd>   <kbd>=</kbd> <kbd>Bksp</kbd>         <kbd>Ins</kbd>  <kbd>Hme</kbd><kbd>PgUp</kbd>

 <kbd>Tab</kbd>   <kbd>Q</kbd>   <kbd>W</kbd>   <kbd>E</kbd>   <kbd>R</kbd>   <kbd>T</kbd>   <kbd>Y</kbd>   <kbd>U</kbd>   <kbd>I</kbd>   <kbd>O</kbd>   <kbd>P</kbd>   <kbd>[</kbd>  <kbd>]</kbd> <kbd>Entr</kbd>    <kbd>Del</kbd>  <kbd>End</kbd> <kbd>PgDn</kbd>

 <kbd>[Caps](http://askubuntu.com)</kbd>   <kbd>A</kbd>   <kbd>S</kbd>   <kbd>D</kbd>   <kbd>F</kbd>   <kbd>G</kbd>   <kbd>H</kbd>   <kbd>J</kbd>   <kbd>K</kbd>   <kbd>L</kbd>   <kbd>;</kbd>   <kbd>'</kbd>  <kbd>#</kbd>       

 <kbd>[Shift](http://askubuntu.com)</kbd>  <kbd>\</kbd>   <kbd>Z</kbd>   <kbd>X</kbd>   <kbd>C</kbd>   <kbd>V</kbd>   <kbd>B</kbd>   <kbd>N</kbd>   <kbd>M</kbd>   <kbd>,</kbd>   <kbd>.</kbd>   <kbd>/</kbd>        <kbd>[Shift](http://askubuntu.com)</kbd>                    <kbd>↑</kbd>  

 <kbd>[Ctrl](http://askubuntu.com)</kbd>  <kbd>[❖](http://askubuntu.com)</kbd>   <kbd>[Alt](http://askubuntu.com)</kbd>                                                                  <kbd>[Alt](http://askubuntu.com)</kbd>   <kbd>[❖](http://askubuntu.com)</kbd>   <kbd>[≡](http://askubuntu.com)</kbd>  
 <kbd>[Ctrl](http://askubuntu.com)</kbd>      <kbd>←</kbd>    <kbd>↓</kbd>     <kbd>→</kbd>

1. Press any of the black keys once.

   OR
2. Don't press any of the orange keys.

Comment: Nope. Depends on the app. Some games will take more keys - including `Ctrl` and `Shift`, for example, but usually not the `Fn` key.

Comment: Full marks for effort, but I really don't see the point of this Q&A. Also, what @muru said.

Comment: @terdon: another [SOHF](http://gaarde.org/acronyms/?lookup=SOHF)?  :P  >:)

Comment: @Tim: Thanks!  I was waiting for someone to do that!  (Much harder then it looks to get it absolutely right...)

Comment: Which group does the spacebar belong to? :-)

Answer (score 8):

I've found that <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> always work.