# Typing guillemets (angle quotes, «») in Russian and English keyboards

Tags: 16.04, unity, keyboard-layout, onscreen-keyboard, russian

I want to type **guillemets** (angle quotes, «») in Ubuntu when using

1. Russian keyboard mapping
2. English keyboard mapping

Is it possible (preferably without typing numeric codes)?

There is a discussion [here](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/1480), but it does not mention Linux.

Comment: Where do you want to enter "guillemets"? In LibreOffice Writer or in TeX?

Comment: @N0rbert Generally in every application, if possible. I usually use LibreOffice Writer and Sublime Text.

Comment: @rapt LibreOffice convert automatically the **"** symbol into guillemet, so that's not a problem on this program; but for Sublime Text, I don't know

Comment: @damadam Is there a setting for that in Writer? When I try, it uses smart quotes e.g. “hello”.

Comment: @rapt What is your desktop environment?

Comment: @rapt Pretty sure, but I don't know which one it is or where it is, my LO is installed by default and give me guillemet when I use " (is it because I use a French keyboard layout? I don't know)

Comment: @N0rbert I use Unity desktop.

Comment: @rapt See my answer below. It suitable for many systems (including  Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity).

Comment: @damadam I recall that in the past I indeed had these «» in Writer by default, and it was annoying since I did not usually want them instead of "" when I type in English. I do not remember if I then found how to change this behavior, but anyway now it types smart quotes by default in Writer. This is also not exactly what I wanted (i.e. dumb quotes).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Below is list of methods to enable special typographic symbols.
For Russian en English layouts they are defined in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/typo` file (mainly based on the [layout proposed by Ilya Birman](http://ilyabirman.ru/projects/typography-layout/)).

As the result you will get the following symbols:

First keyboard row:

- <kbd>~</kbd>              *NoSymbol* ,  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd>              *approxeq*  `≈`;
- <kbd>1</kbd>           *onesuperior*  `¹`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>            *exclamdown*  `¡`;
- <kbd>2</kbd>           *twosuperior*  `²`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>               *onehalf*  `½`;
- <kbd>3</kbd>         *threesuperior*  `³`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>              *onethird*  `⅓`;
- <kbd>4</kbd>                dollar*  `$`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>            *onequarter*  `¼`;
- <kbd>5</kbd>                 *U2030 (PER MILLE SIGN)*  `‰`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>              *NoSymbol*;
- <kbd>6</kbd>               *uparrow*  `↑`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>              *NoSymbol*;
- <kbd>7</kbd>             *ampersand*  `&`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>          *questiondown*  `¿`;
- <kbd>8</kbd>              *infinity*  `∞`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>             *oneeighth*  `⅛`;
- <kbd>9</kbd>             *leftarrow*  `←`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>              *NoSymbol*;
- <kbd>0</kbd>            *rightarrow*  `→`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>              *NoSymbol*;
- <kbd>-</kbd>                *emdash*  `—`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>                *endash* `–`;
- <kbd>=</kbd>              *notequal*  `≠`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>             *plusminus* `±`;

Second keyboard row:

- <kbd>e</kbd>              *EuroSign*  `€`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>              *NoSymbol*;
- <kbd>r</kbd>            *registered*  `®`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>              *NoSymbol*;
- <kbd>t</kbd>             *trademark*  `™`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>              *NoSymbol*;
- <kbd>y</kbd>                   *yen*  `¥`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>              *NoSymbol*;
- <kbd>p</kbd>                 *acute*  `´`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>           *doubleacute*  `˝`;
- <kbd>[</kbd>           *bracketleft*  `[`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>             *braceleft*  `{`;
- <kbd>]</kbd>          *bracketright*  `]`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>            *braceright*  `}`.

Third keyboard row:

- <kbd>a</kbd>                 *U0301 (COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT)* `́`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>              *NoSymbol*;
- <kbd>s</kbd>               *section*  `§`,  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>              *NoSymbol*;
- <kbd>d</kbd>                *degree*  `°`,  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>              *division*  `÷`;
- <kbd>f</kbd>              *sterling*  `£`,  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>              *NoSymbol*;
- <kbd>j</kbd>    *doublelowquotemark*  `„`,  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>    *singlelowquotemark*  `‚`;
- <kbd>k</kbd>   *leftdoublequotemark*  `“`,  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>   *leftsinglequotemark*  `‘`;
- <kbd>l</kbd>  *rightdoublequotemark*  `”`,  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>  *rightsinglequotemark*  `’`;
- <kbd>;</kbd>   *leftsinglequotemark*  `‘`,  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>               *minutes*  `′`;
- <kbd>'</kbd>  *rightsinglequotemark*  `’`,  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>               *seconds*  `″`.

Fourth keyboard row:

- <kbd>x</kbd>              *multiply*  `×`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>                 *U22C5 (DOT OPERATOR)* `⋅`;
- <kbd>c</kbd>             *copyright*  `©`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>                  *cent* `¢`;
- <kbd>v</kbd>             *downarrow*  `↓`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>                 *U25CA (LOZENGE)* `◊`;
- <kbd>m</kbd>                 *U2212 (MINUS SIGN)*  `−`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>    *enfilledcircbullet*  `•`;
- <kbd>,</kbd>         *guillemotleft*  `«`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>                  *less*  `<`;
- <kbd>.</kbd>        *guillemotright*  `»`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>               *greater*  `>`;
- <kbd>/</kbd>              *ellipsis*  `…`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>              *NoSymbol*;

Space:

- <kbd>Space</kbd>          *nobreakspace*  , <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Space</kbd>          *nobreakspace*  .

For other languages layouts may vary.
Settings for common desktop environments are presented below.

---

## Ubuntu with Unity and GNOME desktop environments

### Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

1. Launch GNOME Tweaks (installable with `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`, run by `gnome-tweak-tool`)

   1. Go to **Typing**
   2. In **Miscellaneous compatibility options** check **Enable extra typographic characters**
   3. Close GNOME Tweaks.
2. Open **Keyboard** preferences (or `unity-control-center keyboard`)

   1. Click on **Text Entry**, then on **Keyboard Settings...**
   2. Select key in **Alternative Characters Key** (for example, <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>) (note: it is *3rd level*)
   3. Back to **Text Entry** section, select **Russian** keyboard layout and click small keyboard icon [image: keyboard icon] to ensure that we have guillemets («елочки»):

      [image: Guillemets or Елочки in GNOME]
   4. Close **Keyboard** windows.
3. Use guillemets («елочки») in any application by pressing <kbd>RightAlt</kbd> with corresponding keys (<kbd>Б</kbd> and <kbd>Ю</kbd>;  `,` and `.`).

### Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

1. Launch GNOME Tweaks (installable with `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks`, run by `gnome-tweaks`)

   1. Go to **Keyboard & Mouse**
   2. Click on **Additional Layout Options**
   3. Expand **Miscellaneous compatibility options** check **Enable extra typographic characters**
   4. Close GNOME Tweaks.
2. Use guillemets («елочки») in any application by pressing <kbd>RightAlt</kbd> with corresponding keys (<kbd>Б</kbd> and <kbd>Ю</kbd>;  `,` and `.`).

---

## Ubuntu with MATE Desktop Environment (any version)

### GUI way

1. Open *System -> Preferences -> Hardware -> Keyboard* (or `mate-keyboard-properties`).
2. Go to **Layouts** tab

   1. Click **Options**
   2. In **Key to choose 3rd level** choose needed key (for example <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>)
   3. In **Miscellaneous compatibility options** check **Enable extra typographic characters**
   4. Click **Close**
3. Select **Russian** keyboard layout and click **Show** to ensure that we have guillemets («елочки»):

   [image: Guillemets or Елочки in MATE]
4. Use guillemets («елочки») in any application by pressing <kbd>RightAlt</kbd> with corresponding keys (<kbd>Б</kbd> and <kbd>Ю</kbd>;  `,` and `.`).

### Terminal way

Use GSettings to set two layouts (`us` and `ru`) using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> as layout switcher, typographic symbols are enabled <kbd>RightAlt</kbd> as 3rd level switch::

```
gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.kbd layouts "['us', 'ru']"
gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.kbd model "''"
gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.kbd options \
"['grp\tgrp:alt_shift_toggle', 'lv3\tlv3:ralt_switch', 'compat\tmisc:typo']"
```

## Other GUI sessions and terminal

Edit `/etc/default/keyboard` and add here two parameters as described in [`man xkeyboard-config`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man7/xkeyboard-config.7.html):

- `misc:typo` to enable extra typographic characters and
- `lv3:ralt_switch` to choose typographic symbols with <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>:

  ```
  XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle,lv3:ralt_switch"
  ```

After editing you should update initramfs images to include the new version of configuration file

```
sudo update-initramfs -k all -u
```

Comment: I use the Unity desktop. I tried your "Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS" way and nothing happens. When I am in Russian keyboard and do `AltRight+<`, it prints б.

Comment: Very strange. Just tested this method again on clean Ubuntu 16.04 LTS VM with Unity desktop (followed my guide above line-by-line). With `"RightAlt" + "ю"` or `"RightAlt" + "."` it prints `»`. Do you see 3rd level on the image of keyboard layout chart (accessible from keyboard indicator in right top corner of the screen)?

Comment: I forgot mentioning: in the tweak tool the option is called "Key to choose 5th level" (not 3rd level). I used this option. What does "level" mean? You did not explain this term. Other than this I think I could follow precisely the instructions you had listed. I can open the image of keyboard layout chart, but I do not understand what you mean by "3rd level on the image"?

Comment: On 16.04 LTS 3rd level is named as *Alternative Characters Key* in `unity-control-center keyboard`. Thank you for correction! 3rd-level is next level for `<Shift+key>`, I think. If it is not enabled you have lowercaps and capitals. If 3rd level is enabled you have special 3rd level of typographic symbols (see MATE keyboard screenshot above - it have guillemets and other characters). Please follow my instruction precisely. I have tested it many times. Also see [this page](https://ilyabirman.ru/projects/typography-layout/) about typographic keyboard layout (Ubuntu's 3rd layout is based on it).

Comment: Thank you. It works now (but with a problem). Do you mean that on my system 3rd level is always enabled (available)? As I mentioned, in the tweaking tool,  the only relevant option was to choose a key to enable 5th level (I am not sure what 5th level is), but nothing about 3rd level. THE PROBLEM IS that the key I choose for "Alternative Characters Key" (e.g. `RightAlt`) is not anymore functioning in any shortcut that includes this key. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: I do not think this is a problem. As we enable 3rd level by `RightAlt` then do not use it for shortcuts starting (or containing) `Alt`. Use `LeftAlt` instead. Also you can read somewhere about layout switching [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key). As we do not have hardware `AltGr` key, we may use one from the *Alternative Characters Key* list (for example `RightAlt`). I can't offer more. The method above is complete and working.

Comment: Thank you, it works, I use it. I think they could have done it better by allowing to override the 3rd level by the regular shortcuts such as the ones I have already defined. But generally it's useful to have access to the 3rd level of the keyboard.

Comment: Holy Moly! All that work, clearly formatted, pictures added and still only 1 upvote?  **+1**  Also, you can do keyboards [the hard way](https://askubuntu.com/a/642301/344926)

Comment: You seem to have a sense of humor.  Drop by [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) sometime.  We can use a few more like you.

Comment: OMG finally the solution to all my problems (well, some of them)! guillemets and combining acute in the same layout

Answer (score 6):

On the English keyboard the simplest way I have found is this...
Tap <kbd>Compose</kbd> then <kbd>></kbd><kbd>></kbd>  (2x <kbd>></kbd> in succession) which gives »
Tap <kbd>Compose</kbd> then <kbd><</kbd><kbd><</kbd>  (2x <kbd><</kbd> in succession) which gives «

Comment: does it work with others language keyboard mapping?

Comment: Works on my English UK keyboard so US probably so but I don't have a Russian keyboard... Does the Russian keyboard have the > char? If so, I don't see a reason not to.

Comment: @Graham I do not have that `AltGr` key in my physical Keyboard. Is there a way to work around this? Did they not take it into account? What do you mean by not having a Russian keyboard? You can add the Russian keyboard mapping, no?

Comment: The OP asked for English keyboard mapping which is what I responded to. That said, further research suggests that Ctrl-Alt is the same as AltGr on the Russian keyboard.

Comment: @rapt I amended my answer to show that you can use Ctrl-Alt instead if you don't have the AltGr key.

Comment: @Graham I tested `Super+Ctrl+Alt+<<` on both English and Russian keyboard mappings. It did not work. I am using Unity desktop.

Comment: Does not work for me too (tested on Unity and MATE 16.04 LTS).

Comment: @N0rbert Tap Super then release and tap Ctrl-Alt release then >> works fine for me on 16.04 LTS (don't forget that ">" is a shifted character) using an English (UK) keyboard layout so effectively, you are latching each key press. Can't answer for MATE as I don't have the platform on which to test

Comment: @Graham This is strange, how could this work on Unity? When I tap Super it already invokes the Unity menu (the default behavior).

Comment: @rapt because I've set the right Windows key as the Compose Key and it is that key which I press to generate the characters. I've altered my answer to reflect that to avoid confusion but you are correct; the left Windows key is set as Super on my keyboard and that launches the Unity menu. Sorry for the confusion. I mistakenly thought that Super and Compose keys were one of the same. You can set the Compose key under System Settings> Keyboard> Shortcuts> Typing and that might help avoid confusion.

Comment: @N0rbert Please see my additional response to rapt. I confused the "Super" and "Compose" key terminology. I've amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: Edited to show abbreviated method using only Compose key and right/left angle brackets

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Done!

Comment: @Graham When trying to set the Compose key, I only have the options: disabled, right alt, right ctrl, right win, left ctrl, menu, caps lock. There is no option for left win. Is there a way around this? I simply use the other keys for other combinations.

Comment: @rapt maybe because the left Win key is reserved as the Super key?

Comment: This works with US or Dvorak layouts, but there is no < on the Russian keyboard layout.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently having an <kbd>AltGr</kbd> (Alternate Graphics) key on your keyboard where the <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> resides on US style keyboards is helpful for <kbd>«</kbd> and <kbd>»</kbd> simulation key strokes.

From this [French article](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&u=https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aide:Caract%25C3%25A8res_sp%25C3%25A9ciaux_probl%25C3%25A9matiques&prev=search), translated by google below, it says:

- Under X11 (GNU / Linux) :

  - AltGr w (oss variant) or AltGr z (fr variant) and AltGr x give the left and right quotation marks "and"

Further discussion can be found in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key):

> AltGr (also Alt Graph, or Right Alt[1](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&u=https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aide:Caract%25C3%25A8res_sp%25C3%25A9ciaux_probl%25C3%25A9matiques&prev=search)) is a modifier key found on
> some computer keyboards and is primarily used to type characters that
> are unusual for the locale of the keyboard layout, such as currency
> symbols and accented letters. On a typical, IBM-compatible PC
> keyboard, the AltGr key, when present, takes the place of the
> right-hand Alt key. In macOS, the Option key has functions similar to
> the AltGr key.

There is a lot more to read in the link!

Comment: English page [describes `AltGr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key) key well too.