# Quick insertion of down quotation marks

Tags: input-language, input, special-characters

Is there an easy way to input these quotation marks on Linux: „“ ?

On a Mac, there's a relatively easy compose shortcut, but I couldn't find a shortcut for Linux. There doesn't even seem to be a compose key combination, based on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GtkComposeTable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typing guillemets (angle quotes, «») in Russian and English keyboards](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061647/typing-guillemets-angle-quotes-in-russian-and-english-keyboards)

Comment: @N0rbert I'm looking for specific symbols and that question does not address the bottom quotation marks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Compose</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> for `„` and <kbd>Compose</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd><</kbd> for `“`.

See [How can I add a custom compose key sequence?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47496/how-can-i-add-a-custom-compose-key-sequence/663065#663065) for how to define your own compose sequences.

Comment: Extra info on what the heck is Compose key would be useful, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey

Answer (score 3):

It's easily available in some keyboard layouts, such as *German*:

<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> => „

or *French (alt.)*:

<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> => „

If it's not present in the keyboard layout you are using, please see Florian's answer.

Comment: As I was looking for `«»` shortcuts (which this answer helped find): `«`: `AltGr`+`Z` and `»`: `AltGr`+`X`