# Change to smart quotes On Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Is there a way by which I can enable smart quotes by default so that I always get curly quotes (“) instead of straight quotes (") just like on the mac systems?

I've tried searching for this almost everywhere on the internet and never came to how this can be done either in settings or any other method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typing guillemets (angle quotes, «») in Russian and English keyboards](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061647/typing-guillemets-angle-quotes-in-russian-and-english-keyboards)